# Final steps to secure codeigniter commerce site on vps?

Tags: php, codeigniter, vps

I am about to launch my e-commerce site, which is built on the codeigniter framework, and I was just wondering if there are some not so obvious security things I should do before launching.

I have an SSL cert already to handle in site credit card processing, and I have changed the codeigniter config files to supress php errors etc. I also am utilizing the csrf_protection library and using the tank auth library for logins/registrations.

Is there anything else I should be doing here?

Comment: I'm assuming you've done test transactions.

Comment: yes of course! I am using paypal web payments pro, and have run through about a hundred test transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you done to secure the VPS itself?

Some examples:

- Configured access restrictions on your database and other applications
- SSH access is secured correctly
- Disabled root login
- Removed or secured any other web-facing code, such as phpMyAdmin
- Set up iptables if necessary to block access to local applications

Do you have all your software up-to-date?  You should make sure there are no security updates for the entire OS.

Also, make sure you don't use easy-to-guess passwords on any admin accounts.  When in doubt, make them long and hard to guess.

If you are handling credit cards internally, you should have had to meet [PCI Compliance Standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pci_compliance).

Comment: How would I go about disabling the root login?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificate Check: http://www.digicert.com/help/